# Dict of list of list into dict of tuples of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have this dictionary:

```py
a = {'Jimmy': [['5', '7', '5'], ['S', 'F', 'R']], 
     'Limerick': [['8', '8', '5', '5', '8'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']]}
```

I want the end product to be a dictionary with tuples of tuples, but I think the second loop is not working.

What I want:

```py
a = {'Jimmy': (('5', '7', '5'), ('S', 'F', 'R')), 
     'Limerick': (('8', '8', '5', '5', '8'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'))}
```

Can anyone help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

I tried:

```py
a = {'Jimmy': [['5', '7', '5'], ['S', 'F', 'R']], 
     'Limerick': [['8', '8', '5', '5', '8'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']]}

for key in a:
    a[key] = tuple(a[key])
    for value in a[key]:
        value = tuple(value)
        
print(a)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: So, one key fact: `value = tuple(value)` just creates a new tuple and assigns it to a local variable `value`, that **does not affect the list**.

Comment: Anyway, you would generally do something to the effect of: `a ={k: tuple(map(tuple, v)) for k,v in a.items()}` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement `value = tuple(value)` re-assigns the local variable `value` to a new tuple, but it doesn't change the contents of `a[key]` at all.

In fact, since tuples are immutable, your statement `a[key] = tuple(a[key])` prevents the contents of `a[key]` from changing, unless you reassign `a[key] = something_else`. Something like `a[key] = tuple(a[key])` then `a[key][0] = "A"` will fail because tuples are immutable.

The other answers give nice concise solutions, so you may want to go with those, but here is one that mirrors your original attempt:

```py
a = {'Jimmy': [['5', '7', '5'], ['S', 'F', 'R']], 
     'Limerick': [['8', '8', '5', '5', '8'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']]}

for key in a:
    new_values = []
    for value in a[key]:
        new_values.append(tuple(value))
    a[key] = tuple(new_values)
        
print(a)
```

Here, to get around the fact that tuples are immutable, you can make a list `[]` (which is mutable), build it up over the loop, then convert the list to a tuple, and then finally assign that tuple to `a[key]`.

Answer (score 3):

`value` refers to a fresh variable -- reassigning it does *not* modify the dictionary.

You should use `map()` to transform each list into a tuple, and then call `tuple()` once more to transform the resulting map object into a tuple:

```py
for key in a:
    a[key] = tuple(map(tuple, a[key]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. What you needed is this:

```
for key in a:
    a[key] = tuple(tuple(item) for item in a[key])
```